# React-leaflet don't show correctly in Modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, materialize, react-leaflet

everyone! I try to use react-leaflet in my React Project with Materialize style. When i open Modal component i don't see map. I installed npm install react-leaflet, also added in index.html  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
crossorigin=""/>

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export const MapModal = ({ lnglat }) => {
    const mapRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Clean up the map instance when the modal is closed
        return () => {
            if (mapRef.current) {
                mapRef.current.remove();
            }
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id='MapModal' className='modal'>
            <div className='modal-content'>
                <MapContainer
                    center={[48.0196, 66.9237]}
                    zoom={5}
                    style={{ height: "50vh", width: "100%" }}
                    ref={mapRef}
                >
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    />
                    <Marker position={lnglat}>
                        <Popup>
                            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

MapModal.propTypes = {
    lnglat: PropTypes.array,
};
```

Help me please how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to imports `import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';`  I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an intermediate component to wait for the bootstrap modal to finish initializing, that is, from your main component add an intermediate component, in the intermediate component you must put a set time out, for example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    setShowMap(true);
  }, 2000);
}, [isShowMap]);
//In the return:
{
  showMap ?
    <
    CustomMap lat = {
      lat
    }
  lng = {
    lng
  }
  setlat = {
    setlat
  }
  setlng = {
    setlng
  }
  />:
  <
  div > < /div>
}
```